# Facing issues installing m2e maven plugin for Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, m2e

I installed JUNO Eclipse and then wanted to get the maven plugin for eclipse. After some searching I got to know that I can install the plugin using eclipse market place. So I searched the plugin and installed it successfully but when I restarted eclipse, I cannot see Maven option when I right click on any project. When I click on WINDOWS--> PREFERENCES , I can see the Maven option there. It means, maven got installed but not sure if completely.

I reinstalled it again but still no luck. Can anyone help?

FYI, I am using maven 3.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is still a standard Java project, then you have to enable Maven for this project. You can do this by right-clicking on the project, then choose Configure -> Convert to Maven project. Then you have to type group id, artifact id etc. and the pom.xml is created for you.

Comment: The OP originally said, "I cannot see Maven option when I right click on any project." I'm guessing the OP doesn't see "Convert to Maven project" as a choice.

Comment: Since the menu entry is in a submenu, i have pointed it, because sometimes people don't look in sub menus.

Comment: My java project was already a maven project because I had created it using mvnarchtype plugin. In RAD, my maven plugin identifies the project without the need to convert the project to Maven project explicity(In my company). However, I tried your approach to manually try the "convert to Maven project" option and now I am able to see the maven option properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have installed the Java JDK and add it to the Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

Comment: I have added it but still no luck :(

Comment: If you go to File -> New -> Other...  is there a Maven folder with a Maven Project inside? Also, would you please go to Help -> Install New Software... and then click on the hyperlink "What is already installed?" and verify that you have m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse.